# An infinite moving average is stationary iff its innovations are stationary

Tags: pr.probability, polynomials, time-series

Let $(a_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a real-valued sequence such that $\sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j^2 < \infty$.
Further, define an infinite moving average time series $X = \{ X(t), t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ via
$$
  X(t) = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j \varepsilon_{t - j}, \quad t \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
where $\varepsilon_j$ are zero-mean, finite variance, **uncorrelated** random variables. These latter random variables are often referred to as innovations. In this setting, the innovations are not necessarily independent or identically distributed.

Is $X$ strictly stationary (i.e. all finite-dimensional distributions are translation-invariant) if and only if the innovations are strictly stationary?

The direction "stationarity of the innovations implies stationarity of $X$" should follow from the continuous mapping theorem.
But I can't figure out how to prove the other direction.

**EDIT:** I suspect that this may be related to whether the moving average is invertible. I believe that the MA is invertible if the corresponding polynomial
$$
\theta(z) = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j z^j
$$
fulfills $\theta(z) \neq 0$ for all $\vert z \vert \leq 1$ (I think this follows from a theorem in Brockwell & Davis). But I am not quite sure how the non-zero condition of the polynomial relates to the square-summability of the coefficients $a_j$.

Comment: have you looked at the standard material in, say, Brockwell & Davis on expressing MA series as infinite ARs and  vice versa.  The issue is where the zeros of a fourier series made out of the coefficients lie.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed today that if the zeroes are outside of the unit circle, then the MA is invertible. Then, the innovations could be expressed as a MA of the X's. But in my particular setting the only information I have is that the coefficients are square-summable. Thus, I don't whether the MA is invertible.